# How to remove hard coding of Exe names in C++ application?

Tags: c++, c++builder, ini, hard-coding

I am working on Form application using Codegear C++. All Exe names in the code are hard coded. The Exes are present in a common drive. What is the best way to remove hard coding?
Is it good to use .ini file? If yes, how to go about it? I tried using .ini file, as follows and it did not work:

settings.ini file:

```
[PathSettings]
exe1="R:\\exe1"    
exe2="R:\\exe2"
exe3="R:\\exe3"
```

In the code I added:

```
#define PATH_INI "settings.ini"      //.ini in the same folder
```

To get the path of exes

```
GetPrivateProfileString("PathSettings", "exe1", "", pathExe, 1000, PATH_INI);
//to get the exe1 path into pathExe 

GetPrivateProfileString("PathSettings", "exe2", "", pathExe, 1000, PATH_INI);
//to get the exe2 path into pathExe
```

Comment: Note that the .ini needs to be in the working directory not the same directory as the .exe (unless they are the same). Are you running it from the correct dir?

Comment: Please indent your code properly for SO to highlight (and fixed-width) it.

Comment: @ Dan: Yes, .ini is in the working directory.

Comment: @ phresnel exe names example: R:\\bin\\Auto\\xyz.exe

Comment: @ Chris: Sorry, will be careful and indent code properly here on....